# Review soqls on debug log to avoid too many soqls limit

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I have a test class which calls a visual force page and executes methods in apex controller. Currently the test class is failing on too many soql limits exception. I am trying to debug which soql query is executed multiple times. What is the best way to identify how many soqls are executed, identify any loops in the debug log? What setting in the debug log will tell me how many loops are there, how many soql queries are executed?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: you can run the test class from developer console and you will see the howmany soqls are executed

Comment: Increase the log level for "Profiling" and it will tell you how many times each query is executed amount a lot of other info. Or a simple review of the debug log will reveal the offending query if it is in a loop (pretty easy to spot)

Comment: Unless the codebase is insanely huge with multiple dependencies, I tend to just look at the code and see where the SOQL statements are.  It's usually pretty obvious if the SOQL statements are within a for loop. It just becomes hard if it triggers something, that triggers something else... and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define log level as follows to view finest logs.

[image: Log Level]

For more information refer [Debug log levels](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm&language=en)